# can't launch angular project the problem with git

Tags: angular, git, github

I have a few angular projects each on their own folders when i run one of them with

`ng-serve --port=4500`

another project one gets launched on the same port

can't launch the needed one: i did `npm install` and 'ng serve --port=4500` in the same folder as my project, but how come different project gets lauched?

all project are cloned from github

i found that different project on my node-modules folder deleted it and know getting error:

`

> ERROR in ../../src/app/common/models/calendar.model.ts(1,22): error TS2307: `Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'`.
>   ../../src/app/common/models/date.model.ts(1,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/common/models/navigation-event.model.ts(1,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/common/services/utils/utils.service.ts(4,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/common/services/utils/utils.service.ts(5,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/common/types/calendar-value.ts(1,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/common/types/single-calendar-value.ts(1,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/date-picker/date-picker.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/date-picker/date-picker.component.ts(50,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/date-picker/date-picker.service.ts(3,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/date-picker/date-picker.service.ts(4,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/day-calendar/day-calendar-config.model.ts(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/day-calendar/day-calendar.component.ts(20,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/day-calendar/day-calendar.component.ts(21,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/day-calendar/day-calendar.service.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/day-calendar/day-calendar.service.ts(3,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/day-time-calendar/day-time-calendar.component.ts(26,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/day-time-calendar/day-time-calendar.service.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/day-time-calendar/day-time-calendar.service.ts(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/demo/demo/demo.component.ts(7,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/demo/demo/demo.component.ts(8,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/month-calendar/month-calendar-config.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/month-calendar/month-calendar.component.ts(19,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/month-calendar/month-calendar.component.ts(20,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/month-calendar/month-calendar.service.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/month-calendar/month-calendar.service.ts(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/time-select/time-select-config.model.ts(1,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/time-select/time-select.component.ts(18,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/time-select/time-select.component.ts(19,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/time-select/time-select.service.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.
>   ../../src/app/time-select/time-select.service.ts(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jalali-moment'.

`

Comment: Are you sure another one is actually launched and that you don't just have a process running that you didn't terminate properly? Try specifying a different port to serve on and see if the problem persists.

Comment: yes each time i'm trying to run it at different ports but the result is the same

Comment: i don't fully understand git, i just did for all projects git clone and then git pull, each on their own folders

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear cache and local storage, also try to lunch in incognito window.

Comment: you need to lunch `ng build --prod` first and than in your dist/project folder lunch `http-server ...`